# virt-viewer depends on libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 and libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 but they're not going to be installed

Tags: apt, package-management, kvm-virtualization

```
lz@blade:~$  sudo apt-get install virt-viewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virt-viewer : Depends: libspice-client-glib-2.0-8 (>= 0.33) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libspice-client-gtk-3.0-5 (>= 0.32) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How should I fix it?

I'm on ubuntu 18.04

UPDATE:

```
lz@blade:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates main restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful universe
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates universe
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful multiverse
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-updates multiverse
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Comment: Pleaes provide the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @Emmet done   ,,,,,,

Comment: Why do you have artful (17.10) repositories on your `sources.list` ?

Comment: Please do `sudo sed -i "s/artful/bionic/" /etc/apt/sources.list` to replace it to bionic.